# Highlight words with non alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace

This code

```
$text = 'xxx AA BB xxx xäxAAx xBBBxóx ';
$words = array('AA BB', 'AA','BB');
$text = preg_replace('/(\w*('.implode("|",$words).')\w*)/i', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
```

return

```
xxx [b]AA BB[/b] xxx xä[b]xAAx[/b] [b]xBBBx[/b]óx
```

how to modify to receive

```
xxx [b]AA BB[/b] xxx [b]xäxAAx[/b] [b]xBBBxóx[/b]
```

problem is with non alphanumerical chars, file is in utf-8, text is from mysql in utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` in php is only ASCII based. Replace this with the Unicode character property `\p{L}` and it will work.

```
 $text = preg_replace('/(\p{L}*('.implode("|",$words).')\p{L}*)/ui', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
```

`\p{L}` is a [Unicode character property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), matching any kind of letter from any language

`\w` contains also digits, if you want this, you need to create your own character class like this:

```
[\p{L}\d]
```

this would match letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

You must add at end of pattern regex the modifier `u`

```
$text3 = preg_replace('/(\w*('.implode("|",$words).')\w*)/iu', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
```

And get:

```
xxx [b]AA BB[/b] xxx [b]xäxAAx[/b] [b]xBBBxóx[/b]
```

The pattern modifiers can you see [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Have you tested this? On writecodeonline.com/php this returns the same unwanted result. As I know the `u` modifier does not change the behaviour of the predefined  character classes.